# How Define Disparams (component object model)

Tags: automation, com, components, invoke, idispatch

I want to call an method with invoke. My object input is a string that is address of a file in my computer and type of output is  IDispatch. How I should define Disparams as an input of invoke. My code is :

```
::CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("SGNSAutomation.SGNSApplication"), &clsid);
IID iid;

  HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
  IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*)&pWMPDispatch);
  IDispatch * pdisp = (IDispatch *)NULL;
  DISPID dispid;
  DISPPARAMS  params= {NULL,NULL,0,0};
  OLECHAR * Name = OLESTR("importCase");
//my problem is here
params.rgvarg[1].pdispVal
params.rgvarg[0].bstrVal="E:\\new library\\university\\final project 
documentation\\GPNS project\\net1.gpns";
params.rgvarg[1].scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
params.cArgs = 2;
 params.cNamedArgs = 0;
//

   pWMPDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, 
   &Name,1,LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,&dispid);
   HRESULT hresult =pWMPDispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, 
  LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, NULL, NULL,
                          NULL);
```

please help me to define disparams correctly.

Comment: How is defined the called function "importcase", exactly?

Comment: Hey, @mahdi Lotfi: I notice you've been asking a lot of COM questions lately but haven't been accepting the answers that are given to you. You might get more responses if you use StackOverflow the way that it's supposed to be used.

Comment: Excuse me i am a newbie in stack overflow and i don't know a lot about this site and accepting answers and other options.

Comment: i call this function in this way  IDispatch out=importcase(path of the file in my computer)

Comment: I can answer this question, but we'll need to see the IDL or C++ that defines the interface that you're trying to use. Please update the question with this information.